# Inertial Scrolling in Text View

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView full of parsed HTML, and the content is longer than a phone screen, so I enabled scrolling using

```
tv1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

This works, but it only scrolls directly with a finger. Is it possible to have inertial scrolling, like is found in the web browser, contacts, or basically any other app? I have searched and searched, and have been unable to find out if it is possible for a TextView to have inertial scrolling.

Comment: No, there is no built in support for that purpose. But you can implement your's by tracing the touches on that `TextView` and all. But can't you put that `TextView` in a `ScrollView`? That will give you your desired inertial scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/merriweather_light"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="20dp">


</TextView>
</ScrollView>
```

This worked for me. Just put it inside the ScrollView block

Comment: (Android Studio 2020.3.1 p3)  I had to make the TextView `layout_height="wrap_content"`.